# searching for the times in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, search, character

there, I am new to C++,
The code below is supposed to output all the items containig a certain character I input.
I mean ,if I enter the char 'w',it should output "two" and "water" or when 's' is input the

result shoud be "sabit","sally", and "paris".
So I can not figure out how to modify the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char q;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "bir harf gir" << endl;
    cin >> q;
    string ad[] = {"sabit", "two", "sally", "water", 
                   "mike", "alice", "paris", "david", "martin"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (ad[i][0] == q)
        {
            cout << ad[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your for loop it seems you mean the following

```
for ( const auto &s : ad )
{
    if ( s.find( q ) != std::string::npos ) std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string ad[] = 
    {
        "sabit", "two", "sally", "water", "mike", "alice", "paris", "david", "martin"
    };

    char q = 's';

    for ( const auto &s : ad )
    {
        if ( s.find( q ) != std::string::npos ) std::cout << s << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sabit
sally
paris
```

If you want to traverse not all the array but its part then instead of the range-based for loop you can use an ordinary for loop like

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
{
    if ( ad[i].find( q ) != std::string::npos ) std::cout << ad[i] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking the first character. Instead you can run another loop to check all characters.

```
for(int i = 0; i<7; i++)
{
    for(int j =0; j<ad[i].size(); j++){
        if(ad[i][j]==q){
            cout<<ad[i]<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Although there are lot of other smart ways to solve this, i am just following your code style.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ad[i][0]==q){
   cout<<ad[i]<<endl;
```

Here it is only searching the first character of the word.

The below code can be used as a solution for your problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char q;
cin>>q;
string ad[]={"sabit","two","sally","water","mike","alice","paris","david","martin"};
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(ad)/sizeof(ad[0]);i++)
{   
int len=ad[i].length();
char ch[len+1];
strcpy(ch, ad[i].c_str());
if(strchr(ch,q)!=NULL)
    cout<<ad[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works fine..what if I need to input two or more chars..how can I modify the code? I tried this.."if((strchr(ch,t)!=NULL)&&(strchr(ch,q)!=NULL))" but there may be another way to do that..